# R assigning values from a data frame to colnames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame (called HumMeth450) with data from several samples. The first five rows contain details about the sample, and the followings rows contain the data itself, for example:

```
3B26-1          3A25-1-1        
P16 -           P16 -       
3B-26-clone1    3A-25-1-1-100-1     
Beta Value      Beta Value      
Uncorrected     Uncorrected 
0.765508685     0.598394686 
0.814338487     0
```

I want to set colnames to contain the first five rows from each column.

I tried using

```
colnames(HumMeth450)<-as.character(HumMeth450[(1:5),])
```

and got something that did not match the value of the respective cells, for the two columns cited above I got:

c(469032, 469023, 469031, 469033, 323649), c(467282, 467273, 467281, 467283, 271454)

What am I doing wrong?
any help will be apprciated.

Comment: I suspect you've got factors here, try using str(HumMeth450)

Comment: I assume the values in the last two rows are the actual values you are interested in and the rest is the name of the sample? I would start by reorganizing them to table where the structure is: name, var1, var2.

Comment: You probably want to read the file twice, first to read 5 lines to get the column names, second to skip the first five lines, to get the values.  Otherwise all of your values will be converted to factor levels, which is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, here is how to read 5 lines for the header, then skip 5 lines for the data:

```
text="3B26-1          3A25-1-1        
P16 -           P16 -       
3B-26-clone1    3A-25-1-1-100-1     
Beta Value      Beta Value      
Uncorrected     Uncorrected 
0.765508685     0.598394686 
0.814338487     0   "
```

I create `textConnection` objects here for the example (and don't close them), but you will likely want `file='filename'` in each of the next two statements:

```
a <- read.fwf(file=textConnection(text), width=c(16,16), nrows=5, strip.white=TRUE)
HumMeth450 <- read.table(file=textConnection(text), header=FALSE, skip=5)
colnames(HumMeth450) <- unlist(apply(a, 2, paste, collapse=" "))

> HumMeth450
  3B26-1 P16 - 3B-26-clone1 Beta Value Uncorrected 3A25-1-1 P16 - 3A-25-1-1-100-1 Beta Value Uncorrected
1                                        0.7655087                                             0.5983947
2                                        0.8143385                                             0.0000000
```

Comment: Tiny compaction: you can use unlist(apply(a, 2, paste, collapse=" "))` instead of defining an anonymous function ...

Comment: @BenBolker thanks.  I seem to keep forgetting what the `...` argument to `apply` does.